# SQL records pairing and time interval calculate

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would like to calculate the time interval of specific records.
Here are my SQL query and the records.

```
select event_timestamp, item_id from my_table where event_type='item_clicked' and (item_id='btnA' or item_id='btnB') and user_id='5afcd689c926dc6b1573d7cbff23aa7e' order by event_timestamp DESC

event_timestamp item_id
2018-08-08 12:39:56 btnA
2018-08-08 12:37:26 btnB
2018-08-08 12:37:09 btnA
2018-08-08 12:36:41 btnB
2018-08-08 12:34:06 btnA
2018-08-08 12:33:56 btnB
2018-08-08 12:30:32 btnB
2018-08-08 12:29:55 btnB
2018-07-13 01:48:17 btnB
2018-07-12 03:31:07 btnA
2018-07-12 01:52:50 btnB
2018-07-11 17:01:56 btnA
2018-07-11 16:32:16 btnA
2018-07-09 06:56:49 btnB
```

However, I would like to calculate the time interval of different item_id state changes.

**For example, I want to know that when a user clicks btnA, and how long after he/she will click btnB.
How can I generate a table like this by SQL query?**

```
from_item_id    to_item_id    total_seconds    average_seconds
btnA            btnB          112256           28064

[Note]
2018/7/11  5:01:56 PM -> 2018/7/12  1:52:50 AM: 31854 seconds
2018/7/12  3:31:07 AM -> 2018/7/13  1:48:17 AM: 80230 seconds
2018/8/8  12:34:06 PM -> 2018/8/8  12:36:41 PM: 155 seconds
2018/8/8  12:37:09 PM -> 2018/8/8  12:37:26 PM: 17 seconds
And the total seconds is 112256, and the average is 28064.
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: @D-Shih we use Amazon Redshift, so it seems that it's based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2,.

Comment: How could you create `total_seconds`  and `average_seconds`, is the calculation order by desc or asc? 
I  calculate  `total_seconds` it should be another number could you explain more about it? thanks.

Comment: @D-Shih Sorry I made some mistake, and I have edited it. Thanks for your mention!

Comment: what have you tried so far? do you know window functions? I suggest you remove postgresql tag as postgres <> redshift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `LEAD` window function with `CASE WHEN` in subquery.

Then use the aggregate function `sum` and `count` to get result.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
    event_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    item_id VARCHAR(50)
);



INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-08-08 12:39:56','btnA');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-08-08 12:37:26','btnB');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-08-08 12:37:09','btnA');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-08-08 12:36:41','btnB');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-08-08 12:34:06','btnA');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-08-08 12:33:56','btnB');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-08-08 12:30:32','btnB');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-08-08 12:29:55','btnB');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-07-13 01:48:17','btnB');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-07-12 03:31:07','btnA');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-07-12 01:52:50','btnB');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-07-11 17:01:56','btnA');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-07-11 16:32:16','btnA');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('2018-07-09 06:56:49','btnB');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 'btnA' from_item_id,
       'btnB' to_item_id,
       sum(secondDiff) total_seconds, 
       sum(secondDiff) / COUNT(*) average_seconds
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    (CASE WHEN item_id = 'btnA' 
      and 
         LEAD(item_id) OVER(ORDER BY event_timestamp) = 'btnB'
      THEN extract(epoch from (LEAD(event_timestamp) OVER(ORDER BY event_timestamp )- event_timestamp))
      ELSE 0 END) secondDiff   
  FROM my_table
) t1
WHERE seconddiff > 0;

| from_item_id | to_item_id | total_seconds | average_seconds |
| ------------ | ---------- | ------------- | --------------- |
| btnA         | btnB       | 112256        | 28064           |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f1KmmLKZfJPyQS8juAUQXo/0)

Comment: Yes, It works for me. Thank you very much. Currently, I try to edit the SQL query to meet my additional purpose. This is the golden sample that I can reference. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Andy No problem glad to help :)

Comment: I try to add user_id column in the table. In addition, I would like to list each user's total_seconds and average_seconds. So, I modify the subquery part first and try to meet the same user_id record first. However, it seems that only part of cases work in my real world database. Could you give me some hints? Thanks a lot!! Here is my DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r3tAcBK2wxBbREHuFtd8v/3

Comment: @Andy You can try to use  `PARTITION BY user_id` in window function. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r3tAcBK2wxBbREHuFtd8v/4

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! However, it works in db-fiddle but not work in my real environment (the secondDiff are all zero). I'm checking what's the difference between the two environments...

Answer (score 1):

I would use a condition cumulative minimum to calculate the next b event time.  That seems like the simplest method:

```
select user_id,
       'btnA' from_item_id,
       'btnB' to_item_id,
       sum(datediff(second, event_timestamp, next_b)) as total_seconds, 
       avg(datediff(second, event_timestamp, next_b)) as average_seconds
from (select t.*,
             min(case when item_id = 'btnB' then event_timestamp end) over (partition by user_id order by event_timestamp desc) as next_b
      from my_table t
     ) t
where item_id = 'btnA'
group by user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I will change the table name to try this!!

Comment: I have modified the table name but it seems that it's not working.... Could you help to check it? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kfrbaW1jqZe9Y3wncRoVrT/1

Comment: Your db-fiddle uses Postgres, which doesn't support `datediff()`.  Amazon Redshift does, however.